# Narrow unknown to object

Tags: typescript

I have a function accepting user input, the argument type is `unknown`. I want to assert that...

- `value` is an object
- `value` has a key named `"a"`

```js
function x(value: unknown){
    if(value === null || typeof value !== 'object'){
        throw new Error('Expected an object');
    }

    if(!('a' in value)){
        throw new Error('Expected an object to contain property "a"');
    }
}
```

Typescript complains that "*Object is possibly 'null'*"...

[image: Object is possibly null]

**How can I narrow `unknown` to an object?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

funny enough, you just need to switch the order of your check: ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABADwBQDcCGAbEBTALkXAGsw4B3MASgG8AoRJxGYVKATwAc85hEsuPIgCEAXjGIA5HABGAKzzQpiAD6qBOfIgmSwIbNjqNmpqAAsATpURg8FRAFFL1y6imPkPaHgAmiTCQ5RWVqAG4TJgBfekiWNhF3TBUYJEF8amNTMysbOwdnV3dPbyg-AKCFJShEKDhECAQoTFTELmseS05EACJMHqlwuJiooA))

```
function x(value: unknown){
    if(typeof value !== 'object' || value === null){
        // ^^^^ check type and then check null ^^
        throw new Error('Expected an object');
    }

    if(!('a' in value)){
        throw new Error('Expected an object to contain property "a"');
    }
}
```

This is because checking that unknown is not null can't really narrow, but after the `typeof value !== 'object'` it limits the possible types to `object` or `null` so checking the null case against that type does narrow in the way you want.

Comment: OMG, I can't believe switching the order of the conditions fixes it. Thanks